# Cannot Execute .bat file in PHP wamp

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp

I run my file in the same folder of my php file and also I used an administrator account for Apache to log on with.
Here's my code:
`<?php
    exec("testbat.bat");
?>`

Comment: is safe mode enabled? shell_exec is disabled in safe mode.
Also, if above is alright, if you have not yet checked you error logs, please check your Apache/php error logs first.

Comment: The page just shows a loading sign on the browser and never loads.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php might be helpful

Comment: @JoshulSharma Safe mode is Off

Comment: Alright, Any error in apache logs?

Comment: Try to turn on error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Add this above the `exec` statement.

Comment: @TobiasF. No errors

Comment: @JoshulSharma No errors

Comment: The page just keeps giving me the loading sign on top of the browser..

Comment: May it be possible you bat-file causes an infinite loop?

Comment: @Yang, Refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php : check the Notes section.

Comment: @TobiasF. I cant execute cmd too

Comment: I know I get ignored every time I suggest this but, why don't you use the `$output` and `$return_var` arguments to gather information?

Answer (score 0):

create a file and save it as filename.bat

here is an example

the batch file name is test.bat

```
@echo Hello Houssem...

@pause
```

call it after that from the php file "executeme.php"

```
//to execute the bat file directly 
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START test.bat');

// OR to read Only the content of the batch file 

// the bat file label
$batname = "test.bat" ; 

$output = exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c $batname"); 

echo $output  ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now.

Comment: It writes "waiting for localhost" and it just doesn't load

Comment: Use another local webserver like Wamp - XAMPP , or Check the directory of cmd.exe